# Download file and render template in one request with Flask

Tags: python, flask, request, response

In my application, I'm rendering a PDF file and pass it back as a response. For this purpose I'm using flask_weasyprint's `render_pdf`, which does exactly this:

```
def render_pdf(html, stylesheets=None, download_filename=None):
    if not hasattr(html, 'write_pdf'):
        html = HTML(html)
    pdf = html.write_pdf(stylesheets=stylesheets)
    response = current_app.response_class(pdf, mimetype='application/pdf')
    if download_filename:
        response.headers.add('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=download_filename)
    return response
```

I now need to render a template + returning the rendered pdf as a download. Something like

```
@app.route("/view")
def view() :
    resp1 = render_pdf(HTML(string="<p>Render me!</p>"), download_filename = "test.pdf")
    resp2 = render_template("test.html")
    return resp1, resp2
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is solvable in the backend, you want to send two http responses following one request. Should that be possible? (I really don't know) Shouldn't the client make two responses? (javascript).

An option would be, [javascript datablob](http://qnimate.com/an-introduction-to-javascript-blobs-and-file-interface/) returned in your render_template call.
Maybe something like this? (untested):

```
        fileData = new Blob([pdf_data_here], { type: 'application/pdf' }); 
        fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(fileData);
        window.location.assign(fileUrl);
```

Or maybe just use the window.location.assign() function to generate the second request.

Or put the data base64 encoded in a href attribute?